# Adding data to a MailGun mass email

Tags: php, mailgun

I'm sending out a few hundred emails through Mailgun like so:

```
// Send to Mailgun
$mailgunResult = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
  'from'    => $fromEmail,
  'to'      => $toListString,
  'subject' => $emailSubject,
  'text'    => $textEmail,
  'html'    => $htmlEmail,
  'recipient-variables' => $recipientJSON
));
```

This works fine, but now I want to attach custom data to each email, such as my ID for each email, etc. The docs show how to add json data to a single email, but I can't figure out how to have Mailgun match my list of data to each of the outgoing emails, like it does for recipient-variables.

Anyone done this? My ticket with Mailgun just got me pointed to the docs I already referenced.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to be able to personalize each email by changing the body based on the recipient?

Comment: Also, can you edit your question to provide a link to the docs you mention?

Comment: The docs I mentioned are here: https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#attaching-data-to-messages

No, I don't need to edit the email body. Mailgun wants a 'X-Mailgun-Variables' header with the data json. Then, when an event happens, like a delivery, they will post that data back to me.

I tried this, but the data isn't being posted back to me:

    $mailgunResult = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'h:X-Mailgun-Variables' => $dataJSON,
    'from'    => $fromEmail,
    'to'      => $toListString,
    etc
    ));

Comment: So you want to send a different `X-Mailgun-Variables` header for each email? It doesn't seem like you can do this with Mailgun's API. X-Mailgun-Variables looks like it's per batch, and in addition it looks like it's delivered to every recipient as a header. If you want to send unique data to each recipient, it looks like you have to do that via [recipient variables](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#batch-sending), but those can only be substituted into the body of the message.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Mailgun's template tags in your custom variables. I'm using this to track recipients by a my sites unique id. In your API post payload add the variable using the `v:` style and then use templating (`%recipient.value%`) to set the value for that variable.

An example JSON payload:

```
{
    'v:Recipient-Id': '%recipient.id%'
    'recipient-variables:': { 'email@example.com': {'id': '123'}}
}
```

Then in webhooks payload you'll see the variable like:

`'Recipient-Id': '123'`

I found this out from the helpful blog post on Mailgun's site:
http://blog.mailgun.com/closing-the-loop-between-your-customer-data-and-your-email-data/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped

Comment: I've not (yet?) been able to make this trick work when also specifying the recipient email in addition to the address (`John Doe <jdoe@example.com>`) and when sending messages in test mode. So if someone stumbles here out of despair because mailgun does not replace the variables with their values, try only using the recipient addresses and sending non-test-mode messages and see if it fixes it.

By the way, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah the docs seem to say you have to use just the email as the key for the variables.

Comment: @RB_ thanks! I'd been using Mailgun's **test mode** and couldn't figure out why my logs showed `{"user-variables": {"Recipient-Id": "%recipient.id"}}` instead of the expected substitution `{"Recipient-ID": "123"}`. Switching test-mode off fixed it! (Weird.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, since you say you already looked at the docs.

To me, it *does* look like this is answered in the docs. https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#attaching-data-to-messages:

> ### Attaching Data to Messages
>
> When sending, you can attach data to your messages by passing custom
>   data to the API or SMTP endpoints. The data will be represented as a
>   header within the email, X-Mailgun-Variables. The data is formatted in
>   JSON and included in any webhook events related to the email
>   containing the custom data. Several such headers may be included and
>   their values will be combined.
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```
> X-Mailgun-Variables: {"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"}
> X-Mailgun-Variables: {"my_message_id": 123}
> ```
>
> To add this header to your message:
>
> **API:** Pass the following parameter, `“v:my-custom-data” =>
>   “{“my_message_id”: 123}”`.
>
> **SMTP:** Add the following header to your email, `“X-Mailgun-Variables:
>   {“my_message_id”: 123}”`.
>
> #### Note
>
> The value of the `“X-Mailgun-Variables”` header should be valid JSON
>   string, otherwise Mailgun won’t be able to parse it. If your
>   `X-Mailgun-Variables` header exceeds 998 characters, you should use
>   folding to spread the variables over multiple lines.

When you say "your id", you don’t mean what Mailgun calls a "tag" or "campaign", right?

HTH